# How can i create new objects with a recursive function in Processing to help make smooth random motion?

Tags: java, object, recursion, processing

I'm learning with Processing and I am trying to create smooth random motion. I have successfully done this in a very long winded way and noticed that this would benefit from a recursive function within an object creating new copys of itself. I tried this method but was unable to recreate the behavior i acheived manually.

The manual approach I used is seen below. With a function I generate randomGaussian numbers and update an array with the latest 100 numbers each frame. Taking the average of the array each frame gives a smoother set of random numbers. Iterating this process with the previous output as the input gives smoother still random nummbers.

```
float x;
float y;
int elements;

float[] random;
float[] random0;
float[] random1;
float[] random2;


float sum;
float sum0;
float sum1;
float sum2;

void setup() {
  size(800 ,800);
  frameRate(120);
  
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  elements = 100;
  
  sum = 0;
  sum0 = 0;
  sum1 = 0;
  sum2 = 0;


  random = new float[elements];  
  random0 = new float[elements];
  random1 = new float[elements];
  random2 = new float[elements];

}

void draw() {
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  background(0);
  stroke(255);  
  line(-width/2, 0, width/2, 0); 
  
  
  // random
  for (int i = elements-1; i > 0; i--) {
    random[i] = random[i-1];
  }
  random[0] = randomGaussian();
  for (int i = 0  ; i < elements; i++) {
    sum += random[i];
  }
  sum = sum/elements;
  
  
  //random0 
  for (int i = elements-1; i > 0; i--) {
    random0[i] = random0[i-1];
  }  
  random0[0] = sum;
  for (int i = 0  ; i < elements; i++) {
    sum0 += random0[i];
  }  
  sum0 = sum0/elements;
  
  
  //random1
  for (int i = elements-1; i > 0; i--) {
    random1[i] = random1[i-1];
  }
  random1[0] = sum0;
  for (int i = 0  ; i < elements; i++) {
    sum1 += random1[i];
  }
   sum1 = sum1/elements;
  
  
  //random2
  for (int i = elements-1; i > 0; i--) {
    random2[i] = random2[i-1];
  }
   random2[0] = sum1;
  for (int i = 0  ; i < elements; i++) {
    sum2 += random2[i];
  }
  sum2 = sum2/elements;

  //circle motion
  noStroke();
  ellipse(0,y,20,20);
  float speed = 20;
  y += sum2*speed;
    
  if ((y < -height/2) || (y > height/2)) {
    y = 0;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I create many copys of the same variables and arrays making me suspect an object based approach with a recursive function would be smart.

The object I use in my unsuccessful attempt at this is seen below. I limit the recursive function with the generations variable set to 3 in the main program. This approach seems to only call 1 instance of the function. What is the problem I'm not seeing?

```
class Generator {
  float[] array;
  float output;
  
  Generator() {
    array = new float[elements];
    output = 0;
  }

  float gen(float input) {
    for (int i = elements-1; i > 0; i--) {
      array[i] = array[i-1];
    }
    array[0] = input;
    for (int i = 0  ; i < elements; i++) {
      output += array[i];
    }
    output = output/elements;
    
    if (generations > 0) {
      generations --;
      Generator n = new Generator();
      n.gen(output);
      return 0;
      
    } else {            
    return output;
    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `generations`? It is nowhere defined. Where do you set it to 4 (or whatever)? Please provide the code that is necessary to *reproduce* the problem.

Comment: There is no recursive function in your code. Your `gen(float)` creates a new object, then you call that object's `get(float)` method. A recursive function calls itself (with updated arguments that at some point lead to an immediate return). Also, what is your "regular" code supposed to do? You've created a float array, so by default all its values are 0, then you back-propagate all the values, which does nothing. You still have an all zero array. Then you set [0] to a random value, and then you sum that one value plus all the remaining zeros, which is just that one value. Why use arrays then?

Comment: You do not need recursion here. As a matter of fact, I suspect that it would make your code worse, even if it could be clever. And believe me, I love recursion with a passion. But real non-idiotic examples of needing recursion are surprising uncommon, and it's even less when working as part of a team because you have to make certain that your code is maintainable. Back to this example, I would tell you to use an iterative logic without a hint of a doubt, unless you want to experiment with recursion just for kicks.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for reading! With the gen(float) I am calling the new objects gen(float) with the previous output as input making it recursive.

Comment: Please provide the code that is necessary to *reproduce* the problem. The driving code is missing.

Comment: @firewall only in the "if you squint very hard" sense. You're not making a function recurse,  you're creating a chain of objects that you delegate a single step in a function to (it's similar to recursion, but it's not recursion). So of course the main question is: why are you creating new objects at all instead of using actual recursion, given that those objects are all going to get garbage collected, so why spend the time on object creation and GC overhead?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think I am not quite fluent enough in objects to see the difference.

The "regular" code generates random numbers and fills an array with the latest 100 numbers. By taking the average of the array i get a continually changing random number with smoother movement. By iterating this proces with the previous output as input the change gets smoother with each iteration. 

In the "regular" code I have to define new arrays and variables for each iteration. I was thinking that using an object would be simpler by creating the needed data in the object instead.

Comment: That's not what it does. You start on frame one with an array `random` that is all zeroes. You then run through it backwards, moving all elements in it to the right one spot. So now it's _still_ all zeroes. Then you set `random[0]` to a random number. Now it's an array with one random number, and all zeroes everywhere else. Then you sum and normalize. On the next frame, you move everything again, set a new [0] to a random number, and then resum and normalize. _why_? How is this any better than just generating a new random number directly? You're not making things "more random".